# Float left causes my input label to be on top instead v-align middle

Tags: html, css, css-float

I'm sure there are a lot of people with this problem, but I can't find a proper solution. That is basically is the problem. I've got a form with two pairs of label and field.

HTML:

```
<label for="Account">Inlognaam:</label>
<input class="field" id="Account" name="Account" type="
<br />
<label for="Wachtwoord">Wachtwoord:</label>
<input class="field" id="Wachtwoord" name="Wachtwoord" type="password" />
```

CSS:

```
label {
    width: 150px;
    float: left;
    text-align: left;
}
```

So the problem is: when I don't use the 'float:left;' the input field will be not nice structured. BUT the label is going top-aligned. How can this be fixed?

An example is visible here: http://jsfiddle.net/ptKEh/9/ (comment float:left; to see what I mean)

EDIT::

Another thing... The input fields are in Chrome correct but in IE9 (9.0.8) the second field is a little shorter.

[image: Not equal size fields]

Answer (score 4, accepted):

instead of floating the labels just use `display: inline-block;`
it will preserve the vertical alignment and it works even on IE6 and 7

Comment: Interesting read, i will have to take a look at that in my next project :)

Comment: Thanks a lot :) you saved my day :D. Another thing... The input fields are in Chrome correct but in IE the second field is a little shorter. I'll add a screenshot.

Comment: http://jsfiddle.net/ptKEh/13/ On IE7 and 8 input fields have the same width (I haven't IE9 and 6 to test right now)

Comment: Okay, I know what is the problem. Its a type="password" field. Turns out password fields are for some reason shorter in IE. Do you know a fix for it?

Comment: Problem solved: just put a `input {font-family: Verdana;}` in your stylesheet.

Comment: This worked great, but can someone explain why floating (even with `display:inline-block;`) won't work on labels?

Answer (score 0):

I would recommend using padding to move the text down to be inline. This will only work with 1 line of text for the label and is cross browser capable.

I have put together an example jsfiddle http://jsfiddle.net/ptKEh/11/